# In some cases and with YII_DEBUG=false, Yii is not using my error page

Tags: yii, yii2

My Yii error page is working perfectly, except in some cases. For example if I use

```
// Using "param" instead of params to cause exception
Yii::$app->para['test'];
```

With my config

```
'errorHandler' => [
    'errorAction' => 'site/error',
],
```

Then I set `YII_DEBUG` to `false`

All I get is a white page with

> An internal server error occurred.

Is this normal? With certain exceptions, Yii will just call `die()` or `exit()` with no other details?

Error code:

```
public function actionError()
{
    Yii::$app->session->destroy();

    if ($error = Yii::$app->errorHandler->exception) {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax)
            echo $error->getMessage();
        else
            return $this->render('error', ['error' => $error]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your error action?

Comment: Sure! Updated my question!

Comment: Yes, that's expected behaviour. The `para` property does not exist in Yii2 application, therefore application throws compile error. Since you turn off DEBUG mode it is assuming `production environment` and therefore will not show any sensitive info directly to a user, but logs error into error log file/database (depending on logger configuration).